# How to get entire table data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Datatables Jquery plugin.

I want to get all table datas when I perform click event.

And another task is when I click like copy button, all table datas should be copied to clipboard.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable();

    $("button").click(function (event) {

        var mydata="";

        $("#example tr").each(function (row, tr)
        {

            mydata = mydata
            + $(tr).find('td').text() + ' '
            + '\n';

        });
            alert(mydata);
    });

});
```

Comment: have you tried anything from your side?

Comment: I tried above script to get my table data. but it only returns the table data in html page displays. i want to get all data in the table.

Comment: @nicael i added my script. consider my table have 25 rows of data. but default the page display only 10 rows. then my script fetches that 10 records only. it's similar to after i view another 10 records. my problem is when i click a button i want get all table datas....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fnGetData()` of the datatable to get all data and do your operation on it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    $("button").click(function (event) {

        var mydata=dataTable.fnGetData();

        /*$("#example tr").each(function (row, tr)
        {

            mydata = mydata
            + $(tr).find('td').text() + ' '
            + '\n';

        });*/

            alert(mydata);
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m77qs3p3/5/)**

For More Information see below links

**[how-to-get-all-data](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/8083/how-to-get-all-data)**

**[fnGetData](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnGetData)**

Comment: No response from the script. give some other alternative way..!

Comment: please share jsfiddle link with your problem statement so that I can help you better.

Comment: You need to call `dataTable` (small d) and you are calling `DataTable`(Capital D) function, like this `$('#example').dataTable();`. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m77qs3p3/5/) it shows whole table data in alert.

Comment: $('#example').dataTable(); is acts similar to before i used DataTable. There is no changes...

Comment: check console error logs if any. See http://jsfiddle.net/m77qs3p3/6/ working for me

Comment: error in jquery 1.9.0 plugin - Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead.

Comment: finally i done using fngetdata API. thanks you for your ideas.